# Вырезать часть изображения

Tags: imagemagick, bash, resize

Нужно обработать фотографии средствами ImageMagick.

На фотографиях на белом (либо на градиентах серого) расположен контрастный объект.
Нужно вырезать объект, отцентрировав его в 500x500.

```
find thumb/ -name "*.jpg" -exec convert -resize 500х500^  {} {} \
```

А вот как определить нужные границы?

Comment: что именно вам нужно, кадрировать изображение или сменить ему разрешение?